# Is displacement current the rate of change of induced polarization?

Tags: electromagnetism

I know that the displacement current is proportional to the rate of local polarization change. Yet, I'm not sure if it is technically correct to attribute the displacement current to the rate of change in the induced polarization, as polarization itself is kind of the induced displacement of charges due to some external field.

My gut feeling says that it's not wrong. However, it's confusing as "induction" is really reserved for another phenomenon. But I could be (very) wrong. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can have a displacement current in a vacuum, where there is no polarization possible.

Comment: You are right! I think with my idea, one would again end up with the concept of the ether.